# Recycle WorkflowServiceHost class for versioned workflow. WF 4

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

My scenario is the following:
Workflow XAML is stored in database, then i create WorkflowServiceHost from it and the client can call it. No problem until here: I have XAML1 at endpoint1.

Later the user changes the xaml. As far as i know from other questions, the solution is to keep XAML1, and store the new XAML2 too, and start a new WorkflowServiceHost. 
So ended up with endpoint1/endpoint2 for XAML1/XAML2 and client can decide which to call some way.

Finally my question is, is there a way to detect somehow that the first WorkflowServiceHost has no pending instance inside? I mean all workflows completed inside and you can safely dispose that service host.

At worst case i may use custom tracking participant to log if instance is running, but maybe there is other way....

```
// activity comes from xaml
var jobHost = new WorkflowServiceHost(activity, new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/WorkflowHost"));
jobHost.AddServiceEndpoint("IWorkflowHost", new System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding(), "Job1");
// extensions
// behaviors
jobHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(_instanceStore);
jobHost.Open();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].ServiceDeployments view will contain one record for each endpoind you create. Its primary key, the ServiceDeploymentId, is a foreign key in the [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].Instances view that contains a record per workflow instance. From there it should be a simple SQL query to find endpoints with no related workflow instances.

Comment: Can't see any record in the ServiceDeployments view, Instances view has records of the persisted wf but ServiceDeploymentId column is null. I have created WorkflowServiceHost from code , see original post.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: According to Reflector a VirtualPathExtension is used and it would appear that is not added in a self hosting scenario. And unfortunately the constructor is internal not public.

Comment: What do you think of custom tracking table, one record per workflow instance? Custom tracking participant could log here, with instance status, xaml version, endpoint version. Later SQL query can decide what endpoint is not "active", has no running instances and close that host class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just invoking the Workflow once and then disposing it you can listen to the Closed event for the WorkflowServiceHost.

```
svchost.Closed += SomeMethod;

private void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something after WorkflowServiceHost has closed...
}
```

Comment: I have some long running (few days) instances inside the WorkflowServiceHost, so can't close it.